# Why is there a difference in header behaviour between IOS and Android - Expo Application/React Navigation

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flexbox, expo

Good day!

I was wondering if someone had any insights to this differing header behaviour between IOS (iPhone 6, version 12) and Android (Pixel 4, API 26)? On Android the icon is correctly at the start of the header but on IOS it is stuck in the middle.

[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u38So.jpg)
[IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I0q6.png)

```
const Header = () => {

return(
    <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'flex-start', backgroundColor:'#ff00ff'}}>
        <MaterialIcons name="menu" size={30} color="#ffffff" />
    </View>
)}
```

I am not sure if it is relevant but this component is used as a header title in a stack navigation used in React Navigation.

```
const StackNav = ({name, component}) => {

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

return(
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
            name={name}
            component={component}
            options={{
                headerTitle: props => <Header/>,
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: '#043E22', 
                },
            }}
        /> 
    </Stack.Navigator>
)}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of default behavior of the react navigation. [Read Here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#headertitlealign) On iOS react navigation stack navigator render title in the center, and in android it's render title on the left. If you want to same design for both then make custom header title which you already have done. Now, just add `width: '100%'` and `justify-content: center` to your header style as below :

```js
const Header = () => {

return(
    <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor:'#ff00ff', width: '100%'}}>
        <MaterialIcons name="menu" size={30} color="#ffffff" />
    </View>
)}
```

Also there is a props `headerTitleAlign`, set this to "left" if you want header title in left for both platform or "center" to render title in center for both platform.

Comment: Thank you so much!

The headerTitleAlign:'left' was the key